# Using fabric.js how I can copy a overlay from a hidden image/layer on my canvas using brush

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I am creating a discolor function for designing a jeans pant. I have 2 images of equal sizes one with dark color and other with lighter color. What I want to do is if someone draw a line with brush on my canvas it need to copy same area from a hidden image and need to fill that line with pasting that area from hidden image.

See these images to understand my requirement

Image 1 which showing over canvas.
Image 2 is hidden Image. It must not show on any condition
Image 3 is requirement.

[image: Image 1]
<sub>(source: [hhcnct.com](https://web.archive.org/web/20190831014531/https://hhcnct.com/frontnew.jpg))</sub>

[image: Image 2]
<sub>(source: [hhcnct.com](https://web.archive.org/web/20190831014532/https://hhcnct.com/discolor_front.jpg))</sub>

[image: Image 3]

Like you can see in image 2 top area is not lighter it means if someone brush on top no differnce will occur as both have same color at top.

Should I need to create a hidden layer first from second image?

I am looking a solution in fabric.js because my current base setup in fabric.js.

Anybody can help please?

```
JSFIDDLE Link

https://jsfiddle.net/19kpdwjx/
```

Comment: i can help as soon as i m home! this is the twitter question right?

Comment: Yes @AndreaBogazzi. I need all in fabric.js, So I can undo/delete using fabric functions. I assume I need to create transparent layer like this, but don't how to do in fabric 


       createLayer({
                 name: "discolor",
                 brushClass: fabric.SmoothBrush,
                 background: 
                 document.getElementById("frontimagediscolor").src
                 })

Comment: the discolored picture is not more available to complete the answer.

Comment: I have uploaded that image again you can find that now on same link. https://evolveapothecary.com/jeans-2-discolor-front.jpg, I also using same approach here, https://evolveapothecary.com/fabric
How I can scale brush image to canvas size image?

Answer (score 0):

Need to finish the answer. Had no idea how to save a draft.
Answere incomplete here

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas-front', {
     preserveObjectStacking: true,
     controlsAboveOverlay: true
    });
    
    
    
canvas.backgroundColor = '#ebeced';

window.fabric.Image.fromURL('https://evolveapothecary.com/frontnew.jpg', (img) => {

canvas.freeDrawingBrush.color = new fabric.Pattern({ source: img._element, repeat: 'no-repeat' });
});

window.fabric.Image.fromURL('https://evolveapothecary.com/frontnew.jpg', (img) => {
img.set({
left: 0,
top: 0
});

canvas.add(img);
})


canvas.renderAll();


     canvas.isDrawingMode = true;

     canvas.freeDrawingBrush.width = 20;
```

```css
[hidden] {
    display: none!important;
}
.painting-area{
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    height: auto;
    border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/3.4.0/fabric.min.js"></script>
<div class="painting-area">
  <canvas id="canvas-front" width="680" height="680"></canvas>
 </div>
```

Comment: thanks @Andrea. I need to scale image to according to canvas size so we can keep responsive layout. But then I face this issue

https://evolveapothecary.com/fabric/

Comment: I am getting this issue
https://github.com/fabricjs/fabric.js/issues/4736

Comment: Anybody can help to fix above github issue?